# Display alarms/reminders in android

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences, alarm

I am new to android and developing my first app. I have an application which shows various topics in a list view and the user can set an alarm/reminder on each list item and the application sends a notification at that time using alarm manager, broadcast receiver and notification manager.

I m able to develop this functionality. However now i want create an activity which shows all the reminders set by the user and give functionality of deleting or editing the existing reminders.

However i am not sure how to save these alarms and show them in list activity. I have searched a lot on internet and there are suggestions to use SQLite or shared preference.

If someone can guide the best way to do it or have any resource regarding it,please share it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches:

1. Shared Prefs - Not suitable, usually it's for storing very small amounts of data, usually strings/Boolean flags etc.
2. SQLite - Good option because the expected amount of data is relativly small.
3. Server side DB: Can be SQL (redundant - you don't have here 500MB of data), or it can be NO-SQL, this is better, because you can store `Reminder` object directly and it's logical here. Check the [GAE No-SQL option](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/).